# Something on my site doesnt display until I refresh the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this site http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/
....notice when you first goto the site, look at the top right corner....there is nothing there, refresh the page and in the top right corner my shopping cart appears.

My question is why doesnt that appear in the top right corner when I first goto my site and how would I go about fixing this issue....looking for a step in the right direction here.

Thanks,
J

I even manually put in the cookie in my theme's functions.php file at the bottom like so...

```
function set_new_cookie() {
    setcookie("PHPSESSID", '6a52e6037be6342014834c475b6c0637', time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie');
```

it sets it, it doesn't show any errors, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE, provide the code that makes the shopping cart appear or not appear! [Also, read this article on how to ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just an aside...Why are there a bunch of images of drunk college students representing a jewelry company?

Comment: actually we are all graduates just having a sweet time abroad, I dont have the images ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into wp-ecommerce/wpsc-includes/shopping_cart_functions.php and adjusting this line

```
if ( isset( $cart ) ) {
echo wpsc_shopping_basket_internals( $cart, false, true );
}
```

to this

```
//if ( isset( $cart ) ) {
echo wpsc_shopping_basket_internals( $cart, false, true );
//}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because there apparently must be a cookie set in order for the cart to display.  If you disable cookies on the site, you can actually prevent the cart from ever showing up.

Comment: Yeah the cart won't display until a PHP session has been established with the visitor.  If you delete the PHPSESSID cookie, the cart disappears again.

Comment: I didn't delete individual cookies, but that makes sense.  It sounds like the session isn't being properly established on the first page visit. Hard to tell specifically what the problem is without code samples.

Comment: Yup I totally see the issue now.....thanks guys for the step in the right direction, I really appreciate it