# Wordpress phpinfo cookies issue

Tags: wordpress, cookies, php

Hey ya'll I have this site here http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/ and in the top right corner there is a shopping cart, but it does not show up when you first visit the site, but when you refresh the page it shows up.

I have been looking into this and I think it has to do with this cookie PHPSESSID because when I delete that cookie the shopping cart goes away again.

I have also been told this is a PHP configurations issues.

I tried making some adjustments to my php5.ini file like so...

```
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.use_trans_sid = 0

session.url_rewriter.tags = ""
```

but that didnt work....I got it from here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/frontpage-slideshow-and-phpsessid-in-general-fix?replies=1

Does anyone know which I need to adjust in my php configuration?

I tried to set a cookie in wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php right after the  tag like this...

```
<?php
setcookie("PHPSESSID","6a52e6037be6342014834c475b6c0637","/","http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/") 
?>
```

and then I get this error...

```
Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php on line 54
```

and the shopping cart does not show up when you first visit my site but when you refresh it will still show up.

I even manually put in the cookie in my theme's functions.php file at the bottom like so...

```
function set_new_cookie() {
    setcookie("PHPSESSID", '6a52e6037be6342014834c475b6c0637', time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie');
```

it sets it, it doesn't show any errors, but it does not solve my problem.

I also tried this in my theme's functions.php file...

```
 function set_new_cookie() {

    set_cookie('PHPSESSID', '6a52e6037be6342014834c475b6c0637');
    $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] = '6a52e6037be6342014834c475b6c0637';


}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie');
```

and got this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function set_cookie() in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 5
```

here is the shopping cart form...

```
<form class="product_search" style="font-size:0px !important;" method="GET" action="<?php echo $pp_url?>/" >
                <input name="product_search" id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" class="wpsc_product_search wpsc_live_search_embed .wpsc_live_search" autocomplete="off" style="padding:0px !important; height:25px !important; vertical-align:top;" />
                <script type='text/javascript' > /* <![CDATA[ */
                    jQuery('#wpsc_search_autocomplete').keypress( function(e){
                        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
                            var url = '<?php echo $pp_url ?>'+'?product_search='+jQuery(this).val();
                            url = encodeURI(url);
                            jQuery(window.location).attr('href', url);
                        }
                    });
                     /* ]]> */
                     </script>
                     <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="searchBtn" value="GO"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Did you not ask this question already? I remember already answering this. The problem being that the cookie does not get sent until the HTML source is sent to user, so you would need to manually set $_COOKIE earlier in the script in order to see the cart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something on my site doesnt display until I refresh the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783793/something-on-my-site-doesnt-display-until-i-refresh-the-page)

Comment: But when I try to set the cookie manually I get an error. I will update my question in a minute, just need to recreate the manual cookie and I will show you the error I get.

Comment: You already have another open question about how to set cookies.  Please do not pollute the site with the same questions in multiple places.

Comment: Updated my question. I have the cookie set and get this error.

Comment: manually setting my cookie did not work. Updated my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15349/discussion-between-user1269625-and-mike-brant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue with the shopping cart by going into wp-ecommerce/wpsc-includes/shopping_cart_functions.php and adjusting this line

```
if ( isset( $cart ) ) {
echo wpsc_shopping_basket_internals( $cart, false, true );
}
```

to this

```
//if ( isset( $cart ) ) {
echo wpsc_shopping_basket_internals( $cart, false, true );
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the cookie being set.  Your session_start() will set that. However you need to understand how cookies (including the session cookie) work.  The cookies are sent from the server to the browser in the response header.  So the user will not have the cookie set in their browser until they start getting your response source.  On their next request to the site, their browser will send the cookie with the request.

So the problem is that is you are trying to rely on something in the $_COOKIE superglobal on the first page load, it will not be there (unless the user already had it set from a previous visit).  If you need to work with the $_COOKIE in the initial page load you need to do something like this

```
setcookie('cookiename', 'cookie value');
$_COOKIE['cookiename'] = 'cookie value';
```

Comment: I tried your code and got this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function set_cookie() in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 5`

Comment: @user1269625 sorry I put underscore in there when it shouldn't have been.  That was really only sample code, not meant to be implemented.  To this point you haven't really shared your source code enough to understand what is happening.  Where in your script is the session being started? Where is the cart being initiated relative to that?  The is the sort of code you should be showing in your examples. As most likely the order in which you are doing things is what is causing the problems.

Comment: I dont know where in my script the session being started. Its a wordpress theme. I will look into where the sessions are being started. I will update my question with the shopping cart code.

Comment: Updated my question with the form

Comment: @user1269625 The form itself doesn't really help.  What is the logic that determines if the form is displayed?

Comment: There is no logic that determines if the form is displayed

Comment: `<div style="float:right;" class="taranShoppingCart"><?php echo wpsc_shopping_cart(); ?></div>` this is what is in the header.php file, but im sure this will not help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15360/discussion-between-user1269625-and-mike-brant)